I need the metal spring clip inside the Shimano grip shifter, but can't find one anywhere?
I've seen that this is a common problem, but I've exhausted all my efforts searching for this clip online. The yellow clip in the picture. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Not a duplicate, but relevant https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/75894/why-are-trigger-shifters-so-widely-used-instead-of-the-twisting-grip-shiftersr and worth a read.

Its probably not sold as a separate part.  Given the low cost of the whole unit, a complete replacement one is likely your only option.
Retail seems to be around $16 NZ for example, which is about $10 USD.
Or upgrade to a thumb shifter for added reliability- $32 NZ / $20 USD would buy a Shimano 7 speed thumb shifter which would have better performance and a longer life.
If you're stuck on a grip shifter like this, then good ones do exist but not in the Shimano Revoshift range.  You'd need a SRAM "twist-shift" which are about double the cost.

Agree with replacement of the whole unit. The missing spring indicates it may have been damaged or worn, which infers other parts of the shifter may be excessively worn as well.  While I, too, would much rather spend 10 cents on a part to fix it than the $20 or so for a new shifter, the reality is there aren't any spare parts, and if there were, 10 cents would not be the total price shipped to you.
